# Why doesn't the compose key stay enabled?

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, raspi-config, settings

I set the compose key to be the right logo key using `raspi-config`. (The compose key allows for easy typing of characters not found on the keyboard, like "ü".) Oddly, the compose key works fine for me for a while, then suddenly disables itself, so that I can't use it anymore until re-enabling it in `raspi-config`. The disabling sometimes, but not always, happens when I reboot. Why would the compose key setting not be persistent?

Comment: when this happens could you check `dmesg` to see if there is a kernel event or log message associated with the keyboard driver. to filter message `dmesg |grep keyboard`

Comment: I now at least know that this happens when I reboot.

Comment: check the contents of `/etc/default/keyboard` before and after raspi-config, also make sure keyboard config service is running `service keyboard-setup status`

Comment: @crasic no change occurs in that file before and after the compose key is enabled.

Comment: @crasic Huh. This time it didn't disable when I rebooted, so I _still_ don't know when this happens.

Comment: the `keyboard-setup` daemon is already active